# Apache Spark k-means clustering train data format in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, k-means, rdd

I want to apply k-mean clustering to my data which is in DataFrame format being result of a `sqlContext.sql()` query, in scala. I can convert it to RDD by using ".rdd".

As I understand from the docs and the single example on Spark's website, `KMeans.train` expects RDD vector.

My data consists of two fields, `userid` and `avg`. What I want is clustering the `userid`s according to their associated `avg` values which is in Double type.

Currently I have:

```
val queryResult = sqlContext.sql(s"some-query") //  | userid(String) | avg(Double) |
val trainData = queryResult.rdd
val clusters = KMeans.train(trainData, numClusters, numIterations)
```

leading to this errors:

```
<console>:46: error: type mismatch;
found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
required: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector]
```

That example suggests such a practice:

```
val parsedData = data.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
```

But I cannot figure out how to change it to have an RDD Vector including `avg` data and also mapped somehow to `userid`s.

How can I format my input data to make k-mean clustering run as I expect?

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you want to run a clustering algorithm on the userId & the average? Your schema has the userId as string, is it something like the id or is it more like a username? We might need to apply an extra transformation to convert the userIds into the correct space for kmeans to work on.

Comment: It is intended to be exactly userid, but it is an alphanumeric string. I think I can firstly create a mapping between userid and avg values, and after clustering, use mapping to convert avgs to userids. But since the dataset is too large, a better solution would be great if it exists.